# Alternative to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 for 64 bit access on MDB File

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, 64-bit

I have like many others the problem that I can't access Microsoft Access (MDB Files) from my 64 bit machine using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.

I know that there's no 64bit version of it, and that I need to compile it against x86.

**So my question is:**
Do you know any other .NET Providers for Microsoft Access that supports 64bit access?

Comment: How about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122583/64-bit-alternative-for-microsoft-jet/3049332#3049332

Comment: That's no solution, because the drivers can only installed if no other 32 bit Office version is already at the pc. But most customers will have a 32 bit office version, like Office 2003 / 2007 and so on.

Answer (score 4):

To get 64 bit Microsoft Access drivers download the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255). You cannot install that with a 32 bit version of Microsoft Office installed.

The ODBC connection string with that driver is `"Driver={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};Dbq=%FILE_NAME%;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"`. The OleDb connection string for  that driver is `"Provider=Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider;Data Source=%FILE_NAME%;User Id=admin;Password=;`.

Comment: Is there no standard support for databases altogether in 64bit Windows?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows server 2003, there is the [MSDASQL](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20065) that offer an OLEDB provider for ODBC, which can connect to Access. It is available in 64bits.